# How do I modify a function by a button outside that function?

Tags: swift

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations[0]

    let kmh = String(format: "%.0f",(location.speed*3.6))
    let ms = String(format: "%.0f",(location.speed))

    speedLabel.text = kmh // change [kmh] to [ms] when the button is tapped
```

When I tap this button (`msBtn`), I want the speed label in the function (`speedLabel.text`) to change from `kmh` to `ms`.

```
@IBAction func msBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    // add some magic code here //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a **boolean** inside the class and change that.

```
var shouldDisplayKmh = true

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) { 
    let location = locations[0]
    let speed = String(format: "%.0f",(location.speed * (shouldDisplayKmh ? 3.6 : 1)))
    speedLabel.text = speed
}

@IBAction func msBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    shouldDisplayKmh = !shouldDisplayKmh
}
```

Comment: But what if the situation was opposite, with MS as default, and I want to switch it to KMH when pressing the KMH button? (And to miles per hour when pressing that button and so on..)

Comment: Just set `shouldDisplayKmh` to `false` by default then.